# Ansible: convert Linux path to Windows path

Tags: ansible

I have a task:

```
- name: copy files
  copy:
    src: "c:\\path\\to\\dir{{ item | replace('/','\\') }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ paths }}"
```

I also tried: `replace(\"/\",\"\\\")`, `replace(\"/\",\"\\\\\")` but nothing is working, any help?

`paths` contains: `project/folder1/bin`, `project/folder2/bin`, etc...

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid problems with quotes by defining a variable with backslash as its value:

```
- name: copy files
  copy:
    src: "c:\\path\\to\\dir\\{{ item | replace('/', backslash) }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
  vars:
    backslash: "\\"
  with_items:
    - "{{ paths }}"
```